# Visually selecting from mark to cursor

Tags: visual-mode, mark

How can I visually select the area between a mark and the cursor?

According to

https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_marks

I can yank this range by

> y`a   yank text to unnamed buffer from cursor to position of mark a

but I use a vim plugin that works on visually selected ranges. I did not find such a feat at the above page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work as shown below:
`` v`a ``